# The footer for my Html is not appearing, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: html

So basically the footer isn't appearing in my home page but it shows up in another page when im doing the same thing, what am i doing wrong?

```
<link  rel ="stylesheet" href= "css/home.css" type ="text/css" >

<div class="topnav" id ="myNavBar">
    <a href="/package">Meal Package</a>
    <a href="/registration">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
</div>


  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="homebanner">
  </div>


<!-- FOOTER -- >

<div class="footer">
  <h1>Follow us for the latest deals</h1>
  <br><p>instagram : https://www.instagram.com/aCompany/ <br>
  https://twitter.com/aCompany
  </p>

</div>
```

my css sheet . Also, when expanding the window the .homebanner image zooms in how do i make it so that it goes across the entire window without zooming in?

```
@charset "UTF-8";
.topnav {
    background-color: rgb(11, 10, 61);
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f7f3f3;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  /* Change the color of links on hover */
  .topnav a:hover 
  {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }

 /* home banner */
 .homebanner
 {
    width: 100%;
    height:300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(/images/home/Capture.PNG);
 } 

 .footer {

    width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    background-color: rgb(32, 32, 65);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are adding or caling the footer on that page and other page as well ?

Answer (score 2):

When writing HTML comments, you cannot have space between `--` and `>`.

You need to change your footer comment from:

```
<!-- FOOTER -- >
```

To:

```
<!-- FOOTER -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your footer is commented out.
This is what it should look like.

```
<link  rel ="stylesheet" href= "css/home.css" type ="text/css" >

<div class="topnav" id ="myNavBar">
    <a href="/package">Meal Package</a>
    <a href="/registration">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
</div>


  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="homebanner">
  </div>

<!-- Footer -->

<div class="footer">
  <h1>Follow us for the latest deals</h1>
  <br><p>instagram : https://www.instagram.com/aCompany/ <br>
  https://twitter.com/aCompany
  </p>

</div>
```